# when call Keras Model, then there is no difference between having @tf.function or not. But different when build low-level model

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is this issue a bug?
Compared the following two codes. If include @tf.function then both works well. If not include @tf.fucntion then the custom low-level model does not train.

```
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
# @tf.function
def propagate(x_batch, y_batch):
    """
    Complete both forward and backward propagation on our
    batches.
    """    
    # Record operations to automatically obtain the gradients
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        logits = model(x_batch)
        # Calculates the total loss of the entire network
        loss = loss_fn(y_batch, tf.nn.softmax(logits))
        # Compute the accuracy of our model
        # (Convert our logits to softmax distribution)
        accuracy(y_batch, tf.nn.softmax(logits))
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
    return loss
```

### Compared to when we define custom low-level model:

```
class Model(object):
    def __init__(self):
      self.weights, self.biases = self.initialize_weights_and_biases()
      self.trainable_vars = list(self.weights.values()) + list(self.biases.values())
    def initialize_weights_and_biases(self):

      return out_layer
```

Comment: Hi @MiladToutounchian, kindly include a minimum reproducible code for your case and brief description of your concern.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question and there has been a very interesting conversation in `Github` about it.

A Google Engineer (with Github ID `alextp`) has clarified this question in `Github`.

Providing the clarification here for the benefit of the `Stackoverflow` Community.

The problem is because of using `softmax` and then `cross entropy`, instead of using `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` or the equivalent.

`softmax-then-cross-entropy` is really numerically unstable (you throw away most of the bits of your `logits` when doing `softmax`) and should never be used.

Because of this the `keras cross-entropy` function has logic to "undo" the `softmax` in graph mode:

[image]

So, the solution is to use `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` or the equivalent instead of using `softmax` and then `entropy` separately.

For a detailed and insightful conversation about this issue, please refer [this link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36998).

Happy Learning!